# Google Classroom API - How to format the setFields parameter when retrieving the course list

Tags: android, google-classroom

I am using Java with Android to retrieve a list of Google Classroom courses.
 Here's the code to make the call.  It works fine.

```
ListCoursesResponse coursesResponse1 = mService.courses().list()
                        .setPageSize(30)
                        .setTeacherId("me")
                        .execute();
```

However the Classroom API is rather laggy so I'd like to just specify the parameters I need for each course, which are just the coursename and id.  I'm hoping this will speed up the response time. There is a setFields parameter that can be used, but when I do this the response fails with "Request contains an invalid argument."

Here's the code I am using

```
ListCoursesResponse coursesResponse1 = mService.courses().list()
            .setPageSize(30)
            .setTeacherId("me")
            .setFields("name,id")
            .execute();
```

I'm sure the problem is with the setFields string.  It is most likely not formatted correctly, but I can't find any documentation on how to format the setFields string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer from @Satheeshkumar is not correct.

The `setFields` method is supported and works properly. You can find it on the [documentation for the API client](https://googleapis.dev/java/google-api-services-classroom/latest/index.html).

Also, looking at the API explorer on the [documentation page](https://developers.google.com/classroom/reference/rest/v1/courses/list) you can see that there is a "Show standard parameters" button.

[image: Show standard parameters]

After clicking this you will see the `fields` parameter.

The way this parameter works is by filtering the output and the syntax depends on the structure of the result. By looking at the [response body](https://developers.google.com/classroom/reference/rest/v1/courses/list#response-body) you can see that the response looks like this:

```
{
    "courses": [
        {
            {
                "id": string,
                "name": string,
                "section": string,
                "descriptionHeading": string,
                "description": string,
                "room": string,
                "ownerId": string,
                "creationTime": string,
                "updateTime": string,
                "enrollmentCode": string,
                "courseState": enum (CourseState),
                "alternateLink": string,
                "teacherGroupEmail": string,
                "courseGroupEmail": string,
                "teacherFolder": {
    object (DriveFolder)
                },
                "courseMaterialSets": [
                    {
      object (CourseMaterialSet)
                    }
                ],
                "guardiansEnabled": boolean,
                "calendarId": string
            }
        }
    ],
    "nextPageToken": string
}
```

So, if you only want the `name` and the `id` fields, your `fields` query should be `"courses(id,name)"`.

Comment: @gbotha what is the result of going to [this link](https://developers.google.com/classroom/reference/rest/v1/courses/list?apix_params=%7B%22pageSize%22%3A30%2C%22teacherId%22%3A%22me%22%2C%22fields%22%3A%22courses(id%2Cname)%22%7D) and executing the query?